Git is incorrectly telling me I have read-only permissions to a remote repository?
I have a Bitbucket Server repo that I'm trying to push local commits to but I keep receiving this error:

You cannot push to <project>/<repo>. Pushing requires write access and your access is read-only.

I have admin permissions to the repository. I can make commits via the web GUI with the same user. I don't understand why I'm getting this error.
One thing I think may be related is that I recently also began working with local repos from a Gitlab server using a different username/password so I'm wondering if git is trying to use my Gitlab credentials to push commits to Bitbucket? I can still push commits to the Gitlab repos.
I have my creds configured in .gitconfig like this:
[user]
    name = <my full name>
    email = <my email>
[credential]
    helper = wincred
[user "https://<bitbucket URL>"]
    user="<bitbucket username>"
[credential "https://<bitbucket URL>"]
    provider = generic
[user "https://<gitlab URL>/"]
    user="<gitlab username>"
    password="<gitlab password>"
[credential "https://<gitlab URL>/"]
    provider = gitlab

I've verified this with commands like:
git config --global --get user."https://<bitbucket URL>".user
git config --global --get user."https://<gitlab URL>".user

How can I check what credentials it's trying to pass when pushing the commit? Or any other commands that could help me identify why I'm getting the error.
